# "Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer" Error in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

Hi Stackoverflow Community,

I am looking for some help with Swift 2.0 . I have recently upgraded my Xcode for iOS9 and when building my app, it fails with the following error.

"Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer" - This is in reference to the following snippet:

```
private func isRedirectToApp(url: NSURL) -> Bool {
    if let NSURL(string: self.oauthState.redirectUri)?.scheme,
           redirectScheme = url.scheme {
        return NSURL == redirectScheme
    }
    return false
}
```

Could someone help me resolve this issue maybe or guide me to some resources? I have looked around for help from Apple Resources but to no avail.

Comment: what are you trying to do? you have to assign the value of  `NSURL(...)` to something, like `if let myURL = NSURL(...) {`

Comment: you are confusing classes and instances of those classes quite a bit

Comment: I am trying to understand Swift 2.0 and OAuth by trying to compile this sample Xcode project:https://github.com/soundcloud/iOSOAuthDemo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Safely unwrap the optional NSURL with `if let` then use the non-optional `scheme` property:

```
private func isRedirectToApp(url: NSURL) -> Bool {
    if let redirectURL = NSURL(string: self.oauthState.redirectUri) {
        let redirectScheme = redirectURL.scheme
        return url == redirectScheme
    }
    return false
}
```

Also, you were using `NSURL` instead of your parameter `url` to do the boolean comparison.